# ObservableCollection item doesn't bind toTextBox

Tags: wpf

I am stuked with the following situation:

I define an `ObservableColletion`:

```
public ObservableCollection<Model.OSModel> OS { get; private set; }
```

and instantiate it in the contructor:

```
public MyOSViewModel() // Constructor
{
    OS = new ObservableCollection<Model.OSModel>();
}
```

When added a item to the collection OS:

```
public void OnTabClicked(ListaServicosTab listaServicosTab)
{
    OS.Add(listaServicosTab.vm.OS);
    OnPropertyChanged("OS");
}
```

it doesn't binding do TextBox.

But, if a instantiate the collection inside a method:

```
public void OnTabClicked(ListaServicosTab listaServicosTab)
{
    OS = new ObservableCollection<Model.OSModel>();
    OS.Add(listaServicosTab.vm.OS);
    OnPropertyChanged("OS");
}
```

It Works fine.
Anyone can tell me why that is happening?

My  Xaml Script:

```
<DockPanel Background="CadetBlue" DataContext="{StaticResource OSData}">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Nome}" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="20"/>
    </StackPanel>    
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: xaml code u have posted doesnt have a TextBox.The textblock is binded to a property Nome and that property is not present in the code you have posted.can you add few more details.are you trying to bind a collection to a textbox?

Answer (score 0):

You need to notify the collection changed event of ObservableCollection.

```
 public ObservableCollection<obj> Notifications
    {
        get { return _Notifications; }
        set
        {
            _Notifications = value; 
            NotifyPropertyChanged();                 
            Notifications.CollectionChanged -= Notifications_CollectionChanged;
            Notifications.CollectionChanged += Notifications_CollectionChanged;
            }
        }
    }

 void Notifications_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Notify
    }
```

**MSDN**

ObservableCollection represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need at all `OnPropertyChanged("OS");` you are not replacing OS object instead you are just adding or removing stuff.

The difference between List and Observable collection is that `OS.Add()` is going to trigger the OnPropertyChanged for the "item" in the collection. In List it will not happen. Thats why we use an observable collection which will do all the work for you.

```
public void OnTabClicked(ListaServicosTab listaServicosTab)
{
    OS = new ObservableCollection<Model.OSModel>();// Dont do this
    OS.Add(listaServicosTab.vm.OS);
    OnPropertyChanged("OS");// Dont do this
}
```

Everytime you click you are replacing the observable collection. You will end up having only one object.

```
public MyOSViewModel() // Constructor
{
    OS = new ObservableCollection<Model.OSModel>(); 
       // should initialize only in constructor 
       //not in a place it will be called multiple times
}

public void OnTabClicked(ListaServicosTab listaServicosTab)
{
    OS.Add(listaServicosTab.vm.OS);
}
```

In the XAML you should have an `Items Control` or a `List` to bind this collection not stack panel.